# SendGrid not sending an email through Xamarin

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, sendgrid

I am trying to send a basic test email from SendGrid. My app is connected to an azure server and I have the SendGrid resource on it. I have my api key in the application settings under SENDGRID_APIKEY and I know my app is correctly connected to the azure server because the basic todolist example works perfectly. But I can't seem to get it to send emails, even though I am not getting any compiler errors when I am running it. I decided to test it in on application startup so it wouldn't have anything to do with the app's issues.

My code for sending the email

```
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using static TestApp.Views.Styles.ToDoItem;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Mail;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {


        public static MobileServiceClient MobileService =
    new MobileServiceClient(
    "https://kidneyapp.azurewebsites.net"
);

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



            CurrentPlatform.Init();
            TodoItem item = new TodoItem { Text = "Awesome item" };
             MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>().InsertAsync(item);

            var apiKey = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_APIKEY");
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var msg = new SendGridMessage()
            {
                From = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "DX Team"),
                Subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid CSharp SDK!",
                PlainTextContent = "Hello, Email!",
                HtmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email!</strong>"
            };
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Test User"));
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i suggest you create an empty console app and test it. that way you go all the way in making sure it isn't about something else

Comment: if i remember correctly, sendgrid only sends when you get the sending email address right. else it just sends nothing and tells you nothing

Comment: You are `await` ing within an .ator (that code as shown will not even compile), move all that async/await code to the OnStart override and add async to that method.

Comment: I changed the email address to mine, I just left it this way right now because I didn't want to post my email address.

Comment: I put all the async/await code to the onstart override but still nothing has changed

Comment: What is the `response` value from SendEmailAsync? (also you are not await'ing InsertAsync in that code shown..., you really need to debug/single step through that code to determine if anything else is wrong...)

Comment: Do you test the sending  and receiving email with the same email address? If yes, please have a try to use a different one.

Comment: I used two different email addresses